# display alt tag for image using this - jquery

Tags: jquery, hover

A client wants the alt tag text to appear when hovered (and can't be convinced it should be title, alas). This is as far as I got, but I need only the hovered img's alt tag to display, rather than all of them. I tried removing 'each' but it broke (I know I'm not very good at this). How do I fix it:

```
$("ul.thumb li img").hover(function() {
  $(this).each(function(i, ele) {
  $("li").append("<div class=alt>"+$(ele).attr("alt")+"</div>");
      $(this).mouseleave(function(event){
      $(".alt").css('display','none');
});
});
});
```

[Here it is in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QueTa/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul.thumb li img").each(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').append($("<span/>").text($(this).attr("alt")).hide());
}).hover(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').children('span').show();
},function(){
  $(this).parent('li').children('span').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QueTa/8/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two steps:

```
// create the divs
$("ul.thumb li img").each(function() {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'alt', 
        text: $(this).attr("alt")
    }).appendTo($(this).parent());
});

// toggle the divs visibility
$("ul.thumb li img").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.alt').toggle();
});
// OR attach the handler to the li element instead:
$("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.alt').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/QueTa/9/)

Comment: attaching to the `<li>` will trigger the alt hover when mousing over the lower "more info" text, which is technically a deviation from the original.

Comment: @cdeszaq: Yes I thought about that too. I honestly haven't had a close look at the HTML. It's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.each()`, and you can handle the `mouseleave` as the second parameter to `.hover()`:

```
$("ul.thumb li img").hover(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).parent().append("<div class=alt>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</div>");
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.alt').remove();
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/dPVCN/

NB: I'm remove the `.alt` div altogether on mouseout, since otherwise it would keep appending the alt text over and over again.

A better solution might be to pre-create all of the alt divs, and then just `.show()` or `.hide()` them as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

TheSuperTramp's solution is the best approach, but I've tweaked it slightly to improve performance.

```
$('img', 'ul').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().append('<div style="display:none">' + this.alt + '</div>'); 
}).bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
       $(this).siblings('div').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').hide();
    } 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5dxhC/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You are appending the `div` to all `li` elements instead of just the current one (see @cdeszaq's answer)
2. You are hiding the newly added `div` on `mouseleave` , making all future `.alt` elements hidden. You should use `.remove()` instead of a css property on `mouseout`