# Elegantly annotate an image with the alt tag

Tags: javascript, css, alt

I'd like to elegantly annotate an image on hover (or tap) with the contents of that image's alt tag. I'd like to use only CSS (if possible), and do not want to use jQuery because the page is incredibly simple and I don't want anything superfluous.

Whilst I can't write JS at the moment, I've only been able to find similar examples that use jQuery: [display alt tag for image using this - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806321/display-alt-tag-for-image-using-this-jquery)

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the "alt" attribute is for a description of the image to be used if the image cannot be loaded. The "title" attribute provides behavior like you describe by default in browsers with "hover" behaviors.

Comment: afaik there is no way to retrieve the `alt` attribute using css only. i'd like to be proven wrong though..

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s well modern browsers can get to attributes in limited but useful ways, but tricks with `:before` or `:after` won't work with `<img>` tags because they have no content.

Comment: On some Browsers the rollover uses the alt attribute, others use the title attribute.  Many Smartphone Browsers don't provide rollovers.

Comment: I think you would have to use jQuery or easier, plain javascript. CSS does exactly what it says: altering **style** properties.

Answer (score 4):

Using the HTML5 `<figure>` element you can use the `<figcaption>` element to display the description of the image. It's a semantic approach to the thing you want to achieve. The `alt` attribute is for when the image can not be loaded and be different from the `figcaption`.

```
<figure>
  <img src="/random-image.jpg" alt="Alt description">
  <figcaption>Here comes the description</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You can hide the `figcaption` via CSS and on tap (or click) show it.

Comment: I prefer this over my solution :D

Comment: Yes, this looks better. I'd still like to add the `alt` text though, because it's better for accessibility. I have made a fiddle with jQuery, but I still don't know how to **do this with JS**: https://jsfiddle.net/urbanaut/gynh5cus/5/#&togetherjs=qPDoCCLpNm

Comment: What is the main reason you need/want to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Roy, I'm not using a CMS, and want to write the HTML economically, and, like many people: I have never understood why `alt` content is required, but not displayed anywhere – so, I've never used them until understanding that screen-readers, SEO and `<figurecaption>` are all important parts of a successful page.

The reasoning behind this approach is to: 
– avoid errors
– automate rather than duplicate
– more meaningful content (ie: there's *a lot of images* and stale descriptions won't help keep on-top of key changes to each image).

Comment: The `alt` attribute is required in order to get valid markup, because if the image can't be loaded somehow, it shows the text that's inside the `alt` attribute. If you really want a jQuery solution (which will be ignored on screenreaders), see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17978081/6022243) on another question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but, I want to avoid jQuery and just use JS. This way, I'll be able to let the browser interpret the content properly, and not worry about bloat. I have removed the superfluous styling (I know that's easily possible in CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/urbanaut/gynh5cus/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use :before or :after as @Pointy correctly said. It's a self-closing element, so there is no content. Only attributes.

However, if you can control where the actual alt text goes, you could do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/8o3xqnok/). Which makes use of the content/attr CSS property/combo. For details on this see [David Walsh's post](https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr).

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}

div:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
    content:attr(data-alt);
    color:#FFF;
    background:#000;
}
```

Followed by HTML like this

```
<div data-alt="Sample Alt Text">
    <img src="//placeimg.com/500/300/any" />
</div>
```

Edit: if you want to page to validate, ensure you add an alt attribute to the img as well. Either empty `alt=""`, providing screen readers are able to read out the CSS content (I'm not 100% sure on this, probably depends on the screen reader). Or add the alt text in the alt attribute as well.